# What arguments are passed to an Marpa::R2 action?

Tags: perl, marpa

In the [cpan](/questions/tagged/cpan) page of [Marpa::R2](http://search.cpan.org/~jkegl/Marpa-R2-3.000000/pod/Marpa_R2.pod), I understand the BNF (Backus-Naur Form), but I am quite lost with the action callbacks.

In this example below, I understand that the two, left and right members are passed to `do_multiply`. I have no problem with that. The problem is that I cannot find any documentation of what are these arguments?

```
my $dsl = <<'END_OF_DSL';
:default ::= action => [name,values]
lexeme default = latm => 1    
Calculator ::= Expression action => ::first
...
    Term '*' Factor action => do_multiply
...
END_OF_DSL

my $grammar = Marpa::R2::Scanless::G->new( { source => \$dsl } );

sub do_multiply    { $_[1] * $_[2] }
```

What are `$_[0]` or even `$_[3]`? Where is this documented? Even on the [official marpa website](http://savage.net.au/Marpa.html#Marpa) I don't see any documentation.

In a different example, [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1107117) an answer of [chobora](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1030675/choroba), we see that `pair` refers to `$_[2]` and `$_[3]`:

Snippet of the BNF:

```
Hash  ::= '(' Pairs ')'     action => hash
Pairs ::= Pair+             action => pairs
Pair  ::= '(' Key Value ')' action => pair
Key   ::= String
```

Core code:

```
$recce->read(\$input);
print Dumper $recce->value;

sub hash   { $_[2] }
sub pairs  { shift; +{ map @$_, @_ } }
sub pair   { [ @_[2, 3] ] }               # What is 2 and 3?
sub itself { $_[1] }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Marpe::R2 docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Marpa-R2/pod/Marpa_R2.pod#Semantics) say the following:

> ```
> sub My_Actions::do_add {
>     my ( undef, $t1, undef, $t2 ) = @_;
>     return $t1 + $t2;
> }
> ```
>
> The Perl semantic closures are callbacks. They are called as each node
>   in a parse tree is evaluated.
>
> Each Perl semantic closure is called with one or more arguments. The
>   first argument to a value action is always a per-parse-tree object,
>   which the callbacks can use as a scratchpad. In this example, the
>   per-parse-tree object is not used. The remaining arguments will be the
>   values of the node's "children" -- in other words, the values computed
>   for each of its RHS symbols, in order. If the action is for an empty
>   rule, the per-parse-tree object will be its only argument.
>
> Every value action is expected to return a value. With one exception,
>   this value is passed up to a parent node as an argument. The exception
>   is the value for the start rule. The return value for the start rule
>   becomes the parse result.

So those functions are passed an object as the first argument. That's `$_[0]`.

For your example that text seems to mean that the following arguments, `$_[1]` and `$_[2]` are  just the values that you use to compute stuff.

---

Adding some debug output gave me the following:

```
use Data::Printer;

sub My_Actions::do_add {
    my ( undef, $t1, undef, $t2 ) = @_;
say 'do_add';
p @_;

    return $t1 + $t2;
}

sub My_Actions::do_multiply {
    my ( undef, $t1, undef, $t2 ) = @_;
say 'do_multiply';
p @_;
   return $t1 * $t2;
}

__END__

do_multiply
[
    [0] {},
    [1] 42,
    [2] "*",
    [3] 1
]
do_add
[
    [0] {},
    [1] 42,
    [2] "+",
    [3] 7
]
```

Comment: I don't know why the example has `undef, $t1, undef, $t2` though.

Comment: I also found this piece of documentation, but I am still trying to figure out what is `the values of the node's "children"`. If we take the example of [choroba](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1030675/choroba), [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1107117), we see: `Pair  ::= '(' Key Value ')' action => pair` and  `sub pair   { [ @_[2, 3] ] }`, so what are `$_[2]` and `$_[3]`?

Comment: What did you use to dump your arrays? What is `p`? I usually do `use Data::Dumper; print \@_;`